# PHP/MySQL : why my query doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, cloud9-ide

i'm on cloud9 for a web project, i can insert into my database in MySQL using Mysqli command. But when i try to select data from database my query doesn't work : (the echo $result don't print anything). Any ideas ?

Maybe is better to use PDO command ?

```
    <?php

        //connect
        $servername = getenv('IP');
        $username = getenv('C9_USER');
        $password = "";
        $database = "myproject";
        $dbport = 3306;

        // Create connection
        $bdd = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);


        // Check connection
        if ($bdd->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $bdd->connect_error);
        } 
        echo "Connected successfully (".$bdd->host_info.")";
        $pseudonyme = $_POST['pseudo'];
        $mot_de_passe = $_POST['mdp'];
        $confirm_mdp = $_POST['confirm_mdp'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        if($mot_de_passe == $confirm_mdp)
        {

            $mot_de_passe = crypt($mdp);
            $pseudonyme = htmlspecialchars($Pseudonyme);

            //verifying is user mail is already in base

            $reqVerif = $bdd->prepare('SELECT ID_utilisateur FROM utilisateurs WHERE Adresse_email = ?');
            $reqVerif->bind_param("sss",$email);
            $reqVerif->execute();
            $result = $reqVerif->fetch();

            //user already exist in DB
            if($result)
            {
    ?>
              <div class="nouveau_membre" >
                <p>You already have a account...</p>
              </div>
    <?php
            }
            else
            {
            //in case of new user
             $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO utilisateurs(Pseudonyme, Mot_de_passe, Adresse_email, Date_inscription) VALUES(?, ?, ?, CURDATE())');
             $req->bind_param("sss", $pseudonyme, $mot_de_passe, $email);
             $req->execute();
             ?>

              <div class="nouveau_membre" >
                  <p>New USER !</p>
              </div>
              <?php
            }
        }
              ?>
```

Comment: you can absolutely use mysqli.  see answer below

Answer (score 1):

You are binding only the email parameter, you dont need the 3 "s"

```
$reqVerif->bind_param("sss",$email);
```

try:

```
$reqVerif->bind_param("s",$email);
```

Answer (score 1):

mysqli prepared statements should work.  Just change a couple of lines,

```
$reqVerif = $bdd->prepare('SELECT ID_utilisateur FROM utilisateurs WHERE Adresse_email = ?');
```

You are only selecting ONE string here ,so only list it once:

```
$reqVerif->bind_param("s",$email);
$reqVerif->execute();
```

For your select it is easiest to bind your results, like so:

```
$reqVerif->bind_result($ID_utilisateur);
$reqVerif->fetch();
```

Then you can echo out your result like so:

```
echo $ID_utilisateur;
```

and then close your object:

```
$reqVerif->close();
```

(of course you can do it like you did above;  I just simplified this into its elements)

---

**Edit:** if you want to have it check if there are any rows (which is what it appears), you will need to store the result after the execution with this row:

```
$reqVerif->store_result();
```

and then you can do something like this:

```
$num=$reqVerif->num_rows;
```

and then check it:

```
if ($num > 0) {

    echo $ID_utilisateur;
}
```

and then you can free the result before you close the object with this:

```
$reqVerif->free_result;
$reqVerif->close();
```

Comment: thanx for this extremely complete comment :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)  If it solved your issue, please mark it as solved with the checkbox.